# Recursively Counting A Two Part List with Head/Tail values

Tags: java, list, recursion

I have a homework assignment due and I am not sure how to get started, 
The logic is this, Implement a two part list with strings, The front of the list is head which always holds the first value of the list and the rest of the list is recognized as a tail.
I must recursively find out how many elements are in the list by counting the head every single time and chopping it off and assigning a new head from the tail. The list can be an input of random characters.

Do i need to use the java.util.list feature?
Can i get away with just using a string builder?
How would I assign/ set the head and the tail the values?

Comment: Will you receive the head and tail as inputs to this recursive function?

Comment: Yeah he specifically mentioned it is not a linked list he said its just a two part list with the head as the first character of the list and the tail is the rest of the characters

Comment: Yes i will receive it from scanner

Comment: Wow, I'm thinking of this too much in terms of C, haha. This is done so easily with pointers!

Comment: So, one more clarifying comment -- @linyu21, will you be writing the code to read the input? And you can build the data structure?

Comment: i have some psuedocode i can display

Comment: length (mystring )   if (mystring == [ null]) return (0); else return ( 1+legnth(tail(mystring)));

Comment: i guess i just need to point to the first element in the list and then the tail of the list is the sublist? but i need to do this recursively   #1 count the elements in a list , i will use scanner to input the string as a list of chars, #2 find and delete the nth element of a list

Comment: Hey there -- just wondering if you were able to finish this okay! :)

Answer (score 1):

Only your professor knows what you can and can't get away with, but in terms of a recursive solution, you can maybe think about like this:

Consider this input string:

```
Hello World!
```

Programmatically, you want to think of it like this:

```
head v
     Hello World!
      ^ tail
```

The idea is, as long as `head` contains a character, we can add 1 to the count.

We don't even really worry about `tail`, because after a certain number of recursive calls, we're going to pass in one character as the tail, which is just a head and no tail. Then we'll pass in the empty tail, and your recursive function will hit its base case and return 0 since there's nothing to count in an empty string.

Basically, you have a few things to do.

First, check if the string is empty; if it is, we hit the base case and we can return 0 since there is no length.

If the string *isn't* empty, then you need to add to the count. This counts up the single character in the "head" portion of the string.

And finally, you need to add the length of the tail to the count. This is a recursive call. Consider this: how can you cut the first character out of a string? Once you figure out how to do that, you can pass the resultant, trimmed down string into the recursive function call.

You'll end up with 1 + the length of the tail.

Take a shorter string:

```
 h v
   hello
    ^ t
```

We've called the function, and we determine the string isn't empty, so count goes from 0 to 1 to count the character in `head`.

Now we want to pass in a trimmed down string and get the length of that. So we do something like this:

```
  h v
   hello
     ^ t
```

Notice `head` and `tail` have been incremented. Again, the string "ello" isn't empty, so we add 1 to the count (remember that this is a new function call, so the count is 0 at first). Then we get the length of the trimmed string.

You repeat this till you get to the following case:

```
     h v
   hello
        ^ t
```

Now the string isn't empty, so we add 1 to the count again. Again we pass in the trimmed string to the recursive call.

However, this time, the string is empty since `head` contains no characters. In this case, we return 0 because there isn't anything to be counted.

Now we're going back down the recursive calls. We returned 0 from the last call, so we add that to the 1 we counted in the current call to get 1.

We return 1 from that and add it to the 1 we have in the previous call to get 2.

Return 2, add to 1 to get 3; return 3, add to 1 to get 4; and finally, return 4 and add it to the first 1 we computed to get the length of the string, 5.

Hopefully this makes sense! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It's my code, but I just hope to help you thinking.
The Problem is your homework, so I wish you dont just copy it.

```
public class TwoPartList {

    private String value;
    private TwoPartList others;

    public TwoPartList(String value, TwoPartList others) {
        this.value = value;
        this.others = others;
    }

    public TwoPartList(String[] array) {
        int len = array.length;
        if (len > 0) {
            this.value = array[0];
            this.others = null;
        }
        TwoPartList pre = this;
        for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
            TwoPartList next = new TwoPartList(array[i], null);
            pre.setOthers(next);
            pre = next;
        }
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public TwoPartList getOthers() {
        return others;
    }

    public void setOthers(TwoPartList others) {
        this.others = others;
    }

    public String head() {
        return getValue();
    }

    public TwoPartList tail() {
        return getOthers();
    }

    public void print() {
        if (this != null) {
            System.out.print(value + " ");
            if (this.others != null) {
                this.others.print();
            } else {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] array = new String[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
        TwoPartList list = new TwoPartList(array);
        list.print();
        System.out.println(list.head());
        list.tail().print();
        System.out.println(list.tail().head());
    }

}
```